# Creating and using a dynamic table in C# MVC Entity Framework that is NOT in the EF model

Tags: entity-framework-6

Environment is **C#**, **MVC**, **Entity Framework**, **SQL Server**. The datatype is fixed but the table name is not. It is created to take advantage of certain SQL features during the run. Its name varies by UserId.

The problem is, after creation, as I iterate through my loop, doing my work, I do a query, then an insert. That's record 1. No problem. Next iteration, the query, is set up to pull what was just added and it fails with Entity Framework error.

When done there could be hundreds of users coming through this code at same time and I really don't want to go the dynamic changing of the model route. I'm afraid of blowing up the EF model in production. I want to keep this as simple as possible. The Class "TempProspect" is outside the EF model. So is this temp table. Is it possible EF gets involved because it's in the "Campaigns" schema? Same database? Hope not.

**CREATION**:

```
int abc = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
        ("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='TempProspectsUid" + GlobalConstants.CurrentUser.UserId + "' AND xtype='U')" +
            "CREATE TABLE [Campaigns].[TempProspectsUid" + GlobalConstants.CurrentUser.UserId + "]" +
            "(" +
                "[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL," +
                "[IdxMatchingFirstLastNames1] [varchar] (128) NULL," +
                "[IdxMatchingFirstLastNames2] [varchar] (128) NULL," +
                "[IdxMatchingStreet1] [varchar] (64) NULL," +
                "[IdxMatchingCompanyName1] [varchar] (48) NULL," +
                "[IdxMatchingCompanyName2] [varchar] (48) NULL," +
                "[ProspectGroupId] [int] NULL," +
                "[CompanyId] [int] NULL," +
                "[CompanyName] [nvarchar](48) NULL," +
                "[Department] [nvarchar](48) NULL," +
                "[Division] [nvarchar](48) NULL," +
                "[Position] [nvarchar](48) NULL," +
                "[Gender] [char](1) NULL," +
                "[DateOfBirth] [varchar](10) NULL," +
                "[Title] [varchar](10) NULL," +
                "[FirstName] [nvarchar](64) NULL," +
                "[MiddleName1] [nvarchar](32) NULL," +
                "[MiddleName2] [nvarchar](32) NULL," +
                "[LastName] [nvarchar](64) NULL," +
                "[NameSuffix] [nvarchar](16) NULL," +
                "[PhoneHome] [varchar](24) NULL," +
                "[PhoneMobile] [varchar](24) NULL," +
                "[PhoneWork] [varchar](24) NULL," +
                "[MobileProvider] [smallint] NULL," +
                "[EmailPersonal] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[EmailWork] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[Language] [smallint] NULL," +
                "[Street1] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[Street2] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[PobGeneral] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[SpecialDelivery] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[City] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[StateOrProvince] [varchar](64) NULL," +
                "[ZipOrPostalCode] [varchar](16) NULL," +
                "[CountryCode] [int] NOT NULL," +
                "CONSTRAINT [PK_TempProspectsUid" + GlobalConstants.CurrentUser.UserId + "] " +
                    "PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED( [Id] ASC ), " +
                "INDEX Idx_MatchingFirstLastNames1 NONCLUSTERED(IdxMatchingFirstLastNames1), " +
                "INDEX Idx_MatchingFirstLastNames2 NONCLUSTERED(IdxMatchingFirstLastNames2), " +
                "INDEX Idx_MatchingStreet1 NONCLUSTERED(IdxMatchingStreet1), " +
                "INDEX Idx_MatchingCompanyName1 NONCLUSTERED(IdxMatchingCompanyName1), " +
                "INDEX Idx_MatchingCompanyName2 NONCLUSTERED(IdxMatchingCompanyName2)" +
                "WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, " +
                    "ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) " +
            "ON [PRIMARY]) " +
            "ON [PRIMARY]"
        );
```

**QUERY**:
(I’ve tried this in many different syntaxes, including Object[] and SQLParameter, etc, all fail with the same result)

lstTempProspects = db.Database.SqlQuery
($"SELECT * FROM [Campaigns].[TempProspectsUid{GlobalConstants.CurrentUser.UserId}] WHERE IdxMatchingFirstLastNames2 = '{qm1}'").ToList();

**INSERT**:

```
int numberOfRowsInserted = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
(@"INSERT INTO [Campaigns].[TempProspectsUid" + GlobalConstants.CurrentUser.UserId + "] " +
             "(IdxMatchingFirstLastNames1, IdxMatchingFirstLastNames2, IdxMatchingStreet1, " +
             "IdxMatchingCompanyName1, IdxMatchingCompanyName2, ProspectGroupId, CompanyId, " +
              "CompanyName, Department, Division, Position, Gender, DateOfBirth, " +
              "Title, FirstName, MiddleName1, MiddleName2, LastName, NameSuffix, " +
              "PhoneHome, PhoneMobile, PhoneWork, MobileProvider, EmailPersonal, " +
              "EmailWork, Language, Street1, Street2, PobGeneral, SpecialDelivery, " +
              "City, StateOrProvince, ZipOrPostalCode, CountryCode) " +
              "VALUES " +
             "('" + 
              tp.IdxMatchingFirstLastNames1 + "', '" + tp.IdxMatchingFirstLastNames2 + "', '" + 
              tp.IdxMatchingStreet1 + "', '" + tp.IdxMatchingCompanyName1 + "', '" +
              tp.IdxMatchingCompanyName2 + "', 0, 0, '" + tp.CompanyName + "', '" + 
              tp.Department + "', '" + tp.Division + "', '" +
              …….
              tp.Street1 + "', '" + tp.Street2 + "', '" + tp.PobGeneral + "', '" +
               tp.SpecialDelivery + "', '" + tp.City + "', '" + tp.StateOrProvince + "', '" +
               tp.ZipOrPostalCode + "', '" + tp.CountryCode + "')"
```

**Error**:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

Amateur mistake/simple debugging solution (try/catch):

After realizing I needed more of hint than:
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll

I put a try/catch into the logic and got:
"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to a nullable 'System.DateTime' type is not valid."

Now ain't that a heck of a lot more help? Yeah, messed up string in table and DateTime in model. What can I say? Stupid mistake. Yeah, had some other mistakes with regard to how the indexes were created and the string was built for the SQL Query HOWEVER, it was never Entity Framework's fault as I suspected. Had nothing to do with tracking, etc. All rabbit holes with no rabbit. Just simple date types mismatch.